# node:internal/fs/utils:670 throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, mern

I am getting the following errors when doing some changes but they never get resolved

1. node:internal/fs/utils:670
   throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);
   ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

2. Sometime when I make some changes with help of internet this comes as in console log - post /api/product/create/6291eca0d8edbdf537a8eb4d - - ms - -

This is happening when I am trying to create a product and uploading an image over postman, please resolve I am in need

Screenshots of code

app.js
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqOB6.png)

Product Route.js'
[Product.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rum5r.png)

Product Controller.js
[Product Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOI4c.png)

Product Model
[Product model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxcGY.png)

Code if image not appears

ProductRoute -

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const { create } = require("../controllers/product")
const { requireSignin, isAdmin, isAuth } = require("../controllers/auth")
const { userById } = require("../controllers/user")

//Routes
router.post("/product/create/:userId", requireSignin, isAdmin, create)

router.param("userId", userById)

module.exports = router
```

Product Controller-

```
const formidable = require("formidable")
const _ = require("lodash")
const fs = require("fs")
const Product = require("../models/product")
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler")

exports.create = (req, res) => {
let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
form.keepExtensions = true
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
if (err) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    err: "Image cannot be uploaded",
  })
}

let product = new Product(fields)

if (files.photo) {
  product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path)
  product.photo.contentType = files.photo.type
}

product.save((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  res.json(result)
})
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Product Controller, change the files.photo.path to files.photo.filepath and also changed files.photo.type to files.photo.mimetype

**Product Controller**

```
const formidable = require("formidable")
const _ = require("lodash")
const fs = require("fs")
const Product = require("../models/product")
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler")

exports.create = (req, res) => {
let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
form.keepExtensions = true
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
if (err) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    err: "Image cannot be uploaded",
  })
}

let product = new Product(fields)

if (files.photo) {
  product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.filepath)
  product.photo.contentType = files.photo.mimetype
}

product.save((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  res.json(result)
})
})
}
```